# Seahorse doesn't generate a PGP key

Tags: seahorse

I'm using Seahorse 3.10 (from Trusty). I open it, ask it to create the PGP key. I give the password.

After I've given the password nothing happens at all and no key is generated. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the other answer stated, it simply takes time because not enough entropy (i.e., random data) is generated.

You can **speed the process up** by installing an entropy generator like [haveged](http://www.issihosts.com/haveged/)!

Just install the package via command line:
`sudo apt-get install haveged`

Comment: Would make sense to let the user know about it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to wait up to 15 minutes to gather enough entropy.

Just have some patience.

If you keep using the system, move mouse, etc., it will genererate faster.

Answer (score 0):

After some time I took another look, in fact the key was being generated for so long.