# dpkg command interrupted while running sendmail

Tags: sendmail

I was installing sendmail on my Homestead virtualbox, it got stuck at one point and I used control+c to break it.

Now when I try to run `sudo apt-get upgrade`, it tell me that dpkg was interrupted, try to run `sudo dpkg --configure -a`

when I run that command it starts configuring sendmail but get stuck for a long time at this point:

```
Creating/Updating SSL(for TLS) information
Creating /etc/mail/tls/starttls.m4...
Creating SSL certificates for sendmail.
```

The SSL certificates point takes a long time and never complete.

Please advise.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Certificate generation might take time if your system is low on entropy. See https://askubuntu.com/q/657335/158442 for a similar problem

Comment: Same here... but it never actually completes. I left it for a whole day

Comment: This seems to be a duplicate of question https://askubuntu.com/questions/937666/ubuntu-16-04-command-line-sendmail-installation-hanged, which was answered.